# CMYK SVG in PDFLIB

Tags: pdf, svg, cmyk, pdflib

I would like to use PDFLIB to create a PDF. I would like to import an SVG file which has cmyk colours. I am using PDFLIB's load_graphic. How should I define those colours in the SVG file, to be translated as cmyk in PDFLIB? I tried with icc, device-cmyk, color-profiles, without any luck and there isn't any documentations. Could someone please help?

Comment: Please provide the pivotal code which does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might use the brand new [PDFlib 9.1](http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib/) for this task.

From http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/new-features-in-pdflib-9/ :

> PDFlib/PDFlib+PDI/PPS 9.1 introduces new features related to color handling:
>   ...
>   SVG color extension for ICC profiles, spot and DeviceN color as well
>   as Gray/RGB/CMYK device color for increased usability of SVG for print
>   production

so when you specify the colors as in the [SVG 1.2 Color extension draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGColor12/) you should get the expected result.

PDFlib 9.1.0 is available for free download on:
http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib/

Comment: Thank you. It's working with 9.1. I've tried it with version 9.0.5.